# is it possible to disable ckeditor for private messages?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I've ckeditor through out the site.But i don't need it for private messages(privatemsg module).Is their any way to disable CKeditor only for private messages?

Comment: check from settings or input formates

Comment: I've changed form's input format.It's working fine.Thank you.

Comment: How/where did you change the privatemsg form's input format? I cannot find that setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check from settings or input formates